# ProgressBar till JSONParser return data

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

My app using TabView to show data. One of the TabActivity is corresponding with JSONArray, and one of them is a GoogleMap. When I click on one of them, the app stops for a few seconds and then shows the content. So I have question - how to make it starting instantly with ProgressBar, and when the data were loaded it would start the content of activity. I just can't get how to use ProgressBar(this spinning thing) at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) To download your data. This way your UI won't freeze until data is downloaded.

Always try to seperate downloading data from UI thread.

You can use the `onProgressUpdate()` method to create a nice progressbar.

If you can't calculate any progress you should just enable a dialog without progress range before performing the task and removing it on `onPostExecute()`.

See Usage example in documentation to see usage example.

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

```
private static String url = "address here";
private static final String TAG_CONTENT = "content";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_last_minute);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastMinuteText);

    // Create progress dialog     
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.progressdialog, null));
    progressDialog = builder.create();
    progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading JSON");
    progressDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Whatever",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
    // Show dialog
    progressDialog.show();
    //download json
    new downloadJSON().Execute(url);
}
private class downloadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String allMessages = "";
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params;
        //JSON PARSER
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            JSONArray messages = jParser.getJSON(url);
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < messages.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c;
            try {
                c = messages.getJSONObject(i);
                allMessages = allMessages + c.getString(TAG_CONTENT) + 
                    "\n-----------------------------------------\n";
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return allMessages ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        tv.setText(result);
        progressDialog.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }

}
```

}

Your dialog (R.layout.progressdialog):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, I will try it today, and post a result.

Comment: Everything is all right now, I just can't execute AsyncTask in AsyncTask (i was doing it in my JSONParser class) thanks, for Your help and codes. You're big!

Answer (score 0):

Use the asyncTask

Put this code in oncreate() method

```
private static ProgressDialog dialog;
LongOperation MyTask= new LongOperation();
        MyTask.execute();
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Wait Please");

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Do here what you want Every thing process should be here only
    }      

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
     dialog.dissmiss();

       //now you can see the result here 
    }
}
```

Comment: When i'm trying to put class for example "LongOperation" with modifier private - Eclipse return me error - "Illegal modifier for the local class setTextView; only abstract or final is permitted". So I have to place this declaration beyond `OnCreate` method.

Comment: make a inner class or make a public class